# Parsing a javascript enabled webpage using phantom js

Tags: java, phantomjs

I want to get some field values which are generating after the page load. How to get these fields using phantomjs?

Answer (score -1):

When the php code of page looks like this:

```
$back[avatar] = 'link';
$back[name] = 'John';
$back[age]='18';

echo json_encode( $back );
```

Javascript will look like that:

```
$.getJSON('/script.php', function(items) {
$('#avatar').attr('src', items.avatar);
$('#name').html(items.name);
});
```

You can read more about this here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: What does this have to do with anything from the question?